# How to write if-else in the form of constraints?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want to write the following if-else in the form of linear or mixed integer constraints:

If $Y=k$ then $\phi=\beta$
else $\phi=0$

$Y$ and $\phi$ are variables.

$Y, \phi \geq 0$

$k, \beta >0$

$Y, \phi, k, \beta$ are all integer.

Comment: Does [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55899166/3453768) address your question?

Comment: Also: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Thanks!

Comment: In that question the if term is $a>b$, here we have if $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need *three* new binary decision variables:

- $x_1$ will equal 1 if $Y \ge k$ and 0 otherwise
- $x_2$ will equal 1 if $k \ge Y$ and 0 otherwise
- $x_3$ will equal 1 if $Y = k$ and 0 otherwise.

Let $M$ be a large constant.

Add the following constraints:
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
Mx_1 & \ge Y - k + 1 && \qquad (1) \\
M(1-x_1) & \ge k - Y && \qquad (2) \\
Mx_2 & \ge k - Y + 1 && \qquad (3) \\
M(1-x_2) & \ge Y - k. && \qquad (4) 
\end{alignat}$$

The logic is:

- If $Y > k$, then constraint (1) says that $x_1$ must equal 1, constraint (4) says that $x_2$ must equal 0, and the other two constraints have no effect.
- If $k > Y$, then constraint (2) says that $x_1$ must equal 0, constraint (3) says that $x_2$ must equal 1, and the other two constraints have no effect.
- If $Y = k$, then constraint (1) says that $x_1$ must equal 1, constraint (3) says that $x_2$ must equal 1, and the other two constraints have no effect.

Note that this logic relies on the fact that all of the parameters and variables are integers.

Now add:
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
x_3 & \ge x_1 + x_2 - 1 &\qquad& (5) \\
x_3 & \le x_1 && (6) \\
x_3 & \le x_2 && (7)
\end{alignat}$$

Constraints (5)-(7) say that $x_3 = 1$ iff $x_1 = x_2 = 1$.

Finally, add the following constraint:
$$\phi = \beta x_3.$$
That is, if $x_3 = 1$ then $\phi=\beta$ and if $x_3 = 0$ then $\phi=0$.

I feel like there's probably a simpler way to do this...maybe someone else will have some ideas.

Comment: Thank you so much professor Snyder. Despite the fact that I still have the infeasibility issue with my mathematical model, your suggestion sounds quite reasonable. Inspired by your idea, I came up with a simpler idea as follows:

$Y-k=x_1+x_2$ , 

$x_1-x_2<=(ϕ=β)/M$ , 

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are continuous variables such that: 

$x_1<=0$ and $x_2>=0$.

It would be great to know your idea about this.

Comment: I don't quite understand this. If $Y = k$ then $x_1 = -x_2$, so the second constraint says $2x_1 \le (\phi-\beta)/M$ (I assume $\phi = \beta$ is supposed to be $\phi - \beta$). So then what? How does this force $\phi = \beta$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $Y$ has upper bound $U$.  Introduce binary variables $z_1, z_2, z_3$ and linear constraints:
\begin{equation}
z_1+z_2+z_3 =1\\
0z_1+k z_2+(k+1)z_3 \le Y \le (k-1)z_1+k z_2+Uz_3\\
\phi = \beta z_2
\end{equation}
To check the correctness, note the three possibilities for $z=(z_1,z_2,z_3)$:

- If $z=(1,0,0)$ then $0 \le Y \le k-1$ and $\phi=0$.
- If $z=(0,1,0)$ then $k \le Y \le k$, hence $Y = k$, and $\phi=\beta$.
- If $z=(0,0,1)$ then $k+1 \le Y \le U$ and $\phi=0$.